# iOS Swift: Create Float value from two Ints

Tags: swift

What's the best way to create a single `Float` value from two `Int`s? I have two vars:

```
let int1 = 165
let int2 = 5
```

I'm trying to combine them into a `Float` with the value `165.5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Float to Int

Two approaches.

You can concatenate them into a `String` and pass that to a `Float` initializer:

```
let float1 = Float("\(int1).\(int2)")
```

Or you can divide `int2` by `10` and add `int1`:

```
let float2 = Float(int1) + Float(int2)/10
```

### Int to Float

If you want to go back, you can again use strings:

```
let float : Float = 165.5
let intArray = String(float)
    .characters
    .split(".")
    .map { Int(String($0))! }

intArray[0] // 165
intArray[1] // 5
```

But it's simpler to use math:

```
let (int1, int2) = (Int(float), (float - floor(float)) * 10)
```

Comment: What about the inverse? Creating two Int values from the Float value?

Comment: You could try `let (int1, int2) = (Int(float), (float - floor(float)) * 10)`